# kustomize: add imagePullSecrets to all deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a set of kubernetes config files that work in one environment.  I'm looking to deploy into another environment where I need to add an imagePullSecrets entry to all of the `Deployment` configs.

I can do:

regcred-1.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

kustomization.yaml:

```
bases:
  - ../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - regcred-1.yaml
```

and that will patch only `deployment-1`.

Is there a way to apply the patch to all deployments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `patches` field instead of `patchesStrategicMerge` in order to patch multiple resources.

Based on this [demo example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md) you can do this by specifiyng patch and target selector:

```
patches:
- path: <PatchFile>   target:
    group: <Group>
    version: <Version>
    kind: <Kind>
    name: <Name>
    namespace: <Namespace>
    labelSelector: <LabelSelector>
    annotationSelector: <AnnotationSelector>
```

In this case your `kustomization.yaml` should look like this:

```
bases:
  - ../base

patches:
- path: regcred-1.yaml
 target:
   kind: Deployment
```

Let me know if that solved your case.

Comment: Unfortunately `patches` is deprecated.  I tried `patchesJson6902` and it seems also only want a target that points to a single Kubernetes object, not multiple.

Comment: deprecation note: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/docs/v2.0.0.md#patches

Comment: Indeed but when i look at the newer releases i can see that there is option to do that. [Here is release note for 3.1.0](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/docs/v3.1.0.md#extended-patches)

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize that the kustomize that comes bundled with kubectl is only version 2.0.3.  I installed the most recent release and the `patches` key worked great!

Comment: If my answer was helpful would you consider accepting and [upvoting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)?

Comment: documented here: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/kustomize/api-reference/kustomization/patches/

Answer (score 8):

Using [Inline Patch](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/inlinePatch.md):

```yaml
kind: Kustomization
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
resources:
  - ../../base
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/template/spec/imagePullSecrets
        value: [{ name: image-pull-secret }]
```

Reference: [Patching multiple resources at once.](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md)

Comment: This will replace imagePullSecrets if present.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this seems to work to append an `imagePullSecret`:

```yaml
patches:
    -   target:
            kind: Deployment
        patch: |-
            - op: add
              path: /spec/template/spec/imagePullSecrets/-
              value:
                name: regcred
    -   target:
            kind: CronJob
        patch: |-
            - op: replace
              path: /spec/jobTemplate/spec/template/spec/imagePullSecrets
              value:
                - name: regcred
```

Or more simply, you can just run this once:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
```